# Jackson InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a "GroundPlan" object, which I am trying to serialize/deserialize, however I get the following error during deserialization:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'com.hhuebner.autogp.core.engine.GroundPlan' as a subtype of `com.hhuebner.autogp.core.engine.GroundPlan`: Configured `PolymorphicTypeValidator` (of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator`) denied resolution
 at [Source: (FileReader); line: 1, column: 49]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.invalidTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:2073)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext._throwSubtypeClassNotAllowed(DatabindContext.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.resolveAndValidateSubType(DatabindContext.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver._typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:72)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:66)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:61)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:74)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind@2.13.2/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3642)
    at com.hhuebner.autogp@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.hhuebner.autogp.controllers.MenuBarHandler.openDialogue(MenuBarHandler.java:114)
    at com.hhuebner.autogp@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.hhuebner.autogp.controllers.MenuBarHandler.lambda$initialize$2(MenuBarHandler.java:57)
```

The first three lines of the serialized JSON:

```
[ "com.hhuebner.autogp.core.engine.GroundPlan", {
  "gpSize" : 100.0,
  "components" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ [ "com.hhuebner.autogp.core.component.RoomComponent", {
```

I created my ObjectMapper like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
                    .allowIfBaseType(PlanComponent.class)
                    .build();

objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
```

PlanComponent is an abstract class. I read in some other theads that people also register subtypes like this:

```
objectMapper.registerSubtypes(PlanComponent.class, FurnitureComponent.class, DoorComponent.class, WallComponent.class);
```

It didn't change the resulting stacktrace unfortunately. There are no further annotations I used. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It looks like you didn't allow the GroundPlan class in BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.